# conditionally skipping dll dependencies

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, bluetooth, windows-server-2012

I'm writing a Win8 desktop app to monitor bluetooth status (among other functionalities) using Visual Studio 2012. I've specified Bthprops.lib in the project properties--> additional dependencies. I built a DLL with the bluetooth code and invoke it from a C# project.

Everything works well on Win8. However, when my app is ran on Windows Server 2012, at start-up I get the unable to load DLL because win server 2012 doesn't support bluetooth and doesn't have the dependent bthprops.cpl.

Since I want my app to work on multiple platforms (and don't want users to install additional components), in situations where the platform doesn't have the required dependent file, I want the app to be able to start, skip executing the bluetooth code, and perform the rest of the functionalities.

Is this possible? How would I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear you have to dynamically load the dll using [LoadLibrary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). With that, you don't have the dependency on startup. Additionally, you can check whether loading succeded. If it didn't, the component is not installed. This makes it perferable to mis-using the delayloading mechanism.

In that case, you don't use a library file. Instead, you simply use either a header file or you find the appropriate dll functions using [GetProcAddress()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: thank you for your answer as it pointed me to the right direction. From the dependencyWalker, I saw that my DLL was failing to load on win server 2012 because of the missing "bthprops.cpl". I read that the .cpl is just a specialized dll, do I just dynamically load this file using LoadLibrary() and use GetProcAddress() the same way as I would on a .dll file?

Comment: to be fair - I don't know. But you can easily try it out. Another way around would be encapsulating the cpl in your own dll. That dll loads the cpl on startup using the mechanisms you use before. But you load your dll dynamically. But I assume it is working. It looks like the cpl files are just dlls that follow a specific convention.